# validar xml contra xsd en c#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Quisiera saber si alguien me pude ayudar con esto de la validación, tommé un ejemplo que hay en Microsoft en este [Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=netframework-4.7.2). Creé los dos archivos que muestran en el ejemplo y funciona, si le agrego un dato, me salta un error de que hay un campo que no pertenece.

Por la pega, me pasaron un xsd y ejemplos de documentos xml, yo tuve que generar mi XML sacando los datos de una base de datos (dejo este [LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WslmTOQ1wcAYWteXB86Y0LRE52nDAr81?usp=sharing) del xsd y el xml que los tengo en Google Drive para no pegar tanto código).

El tema es que cuando paso estos dos archivos por mi aplicación no me muestra ningún mensaje de error en la validación inclusive si le agrego un campo. Por lo tanto debo de entender que o no está comparando o se está saltando algo que no veo, este es el código de la aplicación.

```
private static string ar_xml = @"C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\ValidarXmlXsd\archivo_xml.xml";
        private static string ar_xsd = @"C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\ValidarXmlXsd\DocIngreso.xsd";
        private string esquema = "http://www.aduana.cl/xml/esquemas/zf/ingreso/v2";


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.Schemas.Add(esquema, ar_xsd);
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ar_xml, settings);
                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.Load(reader);

                ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

                // the following call to Validate succeeds.
                document.Validate(eventHandler);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            }

        }

        static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Severity.ToString());
            switch (e.Severity)
            {
                case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error: {0}", e.Message));
                    break;
                case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Warning {0}", e.Message));
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Creé tres variables, dos para la ubicación de los archivos y la otra para el esquema, si esta última no se la pongo me alega que debo pasarla.

Entiendo el código y qué es lo que está haciendo pero creo que mi error puede estar entre el xsd y el xml, si alguien me puede orientar se los agradezco.

Gracias

Comment: Te recomiendo que inicies con un ejemplo xml sencillo, digamos una persona con datos de nombre, telefono, direccion, y valides algunos de esos campos. Ya cuando hayas entendido el mecanismo puedes intentar con el xml real de tu problema. Despues debes ir identificando las reglas de tu xml, si algun elmento es opcional, si debe cumplir un patron, si alguna secuencia debe conterner un determinado numero de items, etc. esto para despues armar tu schema de validacion.

Comment: Hola, como comento hice el ejercicio simple con los archivos que ponen en la página de microsoft y eso lo entendí bien. Pero.. si toma el archivo xml y lo valida contra el xsd y hay algún error  debería saltarme un error si, como dices tú, hay alguna regla. Y esto es lo que no se está haciendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para  leer los errores de validacion en caso que haya puedes usar este metodo:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xsdFile = @"aqui el path de tu schema";
            string xmlFile = @"aqui el path de tu archivo xml";

            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
            var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(xsdFile))
            {
                schemas.Add(XmlSchema.Read(stream, (s, e) =>
                {
                    var x = e.Message;
                }));
            }

            bool isvalid = true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                xdoc.Validate(schemas, (s, e) =>
                {
                    isvalid = false;
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Line : {0}, Message : {1} ",
                        e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.Message));
                });
            }
            catch (XmlSchemaValidationException)
            {
                isvalid = false;
            }

            //var errores= sb.ToString();
            //puedes guardar la cadena errores en un log.
            Console.Write(sb);

            Console.Read();
        }
```

Nota: tu archivo xsd, parece mal formado intenta eliminar "ingreso:" en todas las referencias y tambien el la declaracion de nombre de dominio, te debe quedar algo asi:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="documento">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="cabecera"/>
                    <xs:element ref="documentosadjuntos" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Una vez que hagas esto te saldran bastantes errores de tu documento xml pero eso es lo que se busca, los datos erroneos.

saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda pero no quiero leer los errores de validación. Como comenté en mi pregunta, ese código de ejemplo funciona, pero por algún motivo cuando lo aplico a los archivos que tengo yo, no me da ningún tipo de mensaje de error. Es como que se pasa por alto los archivos o la validación

Comment: Usa este codigo para validar en un metodo y retorna la variable isvalid, agrega otro catch para excepcion general y tendras lo que buscas, este codigo es mas simple que el que presentas y si no carga el archivo xml o del esquema te envia una excepcion.

Comment: Copié tu código tal cual para probar y le cambié el Console.Write(sb); por **MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())** y no me muestra nada. Gracias por tu ayuda pero voy a parar por hoy, llevo un mes programando en c# y ya me tiene colapsado

Comment: igual lo encuentro raro porque hice la prueba con los archivos de ejemplo que salen en la página de microsoft y claro, si modifico el xml, con tu código, me salta error altiro, si no lo hago no muestra ningún mensaje. Pero para el caso de los archivos que tengo yo. En ningún caso muestra error de algo y ese es el quebradero de cabeza que tengo , Mañana voy a comparar bien en qué se diferencian

Comment: Buenos Días, tenías razón eliminé lo que me comentaste y empezaron a saltar muchos errores, eso quiere decir que tengo mal hecho mi xml, pero tengo una duda, Cómo determinaste que el xsd estaba mal formado? porque se supone que este es un documento oficial..

Comment: Pues tenia 15 min libres asi que descargue tus archivos e hice pruebas todo parecia bien,  elimine partes del xml y siguio validando bien, eso significaba que el esquema no tenia reglas declaradas, abri el esquema y todo estaba declarado; la declaracion de ingreso hacia referencia a un doc en la nube no a las propiedades declaradas localmente, por eso elimine la url de "ingreso" , de esta manera las declaraciones en el esquema se toman en cuenta.

Comment: a ok, es un problema más o menos este tema de las validaciones, pero gracias por todo. Quedó funcionando

Answer (score 2):

Prueba cambiando esta parte

```
settings.Schemas.Add(esquema, ar_xsd);
```

por

```
setting.Schemas.Add(null, XmlReader.Create(schemaPath));
```

Comment: Igual voy a hacer la prueba pero, el **schemaPath** vendría a ser donde tengo ubicado el xsd?

Comment: si, seria la ruta en tu caso  private static string ar_xsd = @"C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\ValidarXmlXsd\DocIngreso.xsd";